# Save text form TinyMCE Editor to XML file?

Tags: php, xml

I write an web page to load text form an XML file to edit on TinyMCE editor. But when i write xml it contain special character like this: `&lt;p&gt;&aacute;dasd&lt;/p&gt;` and when i try to read that XMl file again it break. Anybody can tell me how to fix that bug:(. Thanks you verry much.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're double-encoding, but your description isn't very clear. Somewhere, you've got text which is already XML but you're probably trying to write it as text *within* an XML element, which is escaping it again.

If you could lay out the *exact* steps you're taking - what programs are involved, what they're doing, where they're getting input from, where they're writing it to and how, it should be easy enough to work out how to fix it.